# What is the Java regex to use back-references and capture groups correctly

Tags: java, xml, regex

I want to strip a SOAP envelope from a message to get at the XML in the body.

I attempted the following;

```
String strippedOfEnvelopedHeader = msg.replaceAll("(?s)(?i)<(.*):Envelope.*<\1:Body>", "");
```

I thought that this would stip out the SOAP envelope, specifically the header, from a message like;

`<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>

   <env:Header xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'/>

   <soapenv:Body>

        <myXML> stuff is here</myXML>

   </soapenv:Body>

</soapenv:Envelope>`

which should result in;

`<myXML> stuff is here</myXML>

   </soapenv:Body>

</soapenv:Envelope>`

However, the group back-reference does not seem to work.

If I replace both the capture group and the back-reference the substitution works fine;

```
String strippedOfEnvelopeHeader = msg.replaceAll("(?i)(?s)<soapenv:Envelope.*<soapenv:Body>", "");
```

I think I can guess the problem, the capture group is being greedy and grabbing the entire message and thus failing the match.

But the solution evades me.

Any ideas?

Comment: argh regexes to parse markup.... I don't know soap but it looks like it's xml itself? If so, use an xml parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try 2 backslashes

```
"(?si)<(.*):Envelope.*<\\1:Body>"
```

You need 2 because `\1` itself is already a special escape sequence to Java. Therefore it will be decoded into the character U+0001 before feeding to the regex engine. You need to protect it by adding one more backslash.

(And the usual "don't parse XML with Regex" warning follows...)

Comment: yeah. I hate using regex for this. But I am stuck with finding a way around a mess of legacy jar dependencies that have blocked using Axis or JAX-WS. I got JAXB working for the body though, so this is the limit of my hackery. [Plus the code will be replaced in 9 months]

Comment: I found a 'safer' way using org.w3c.dom.Document. The JAXB unmarshaller can take a DOM Node object, so I just grab the contents of the Body element using DOM and then pass this node to the unmarshaller. Of course, this is over 20 lines of code, a bunch of extra imports, and a try-catch, and the regex is a single line of code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String strippedOfEnvelopedHeader = msg.replaceAll("(?s)<(\\w+):Envelope[^<>]*>.*?<\\1:Body>", "");
```

Key points:

1. As already pointed out by others,  backslashes in Java strings need to be escaped.  So every backslash in your regex becomes a double backslash when formatting the regex as a Java string.
2. You're [using the dot inappropriately](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html).  You cannot have *any character* as the XML namespace.  You cannot have *any character* inside XML tags.  Make your regex more specific by using (negated) character classes, and you'll easily avoid problems with `.*` eating up more than it should.  I left one `.*?` in my regex because I don't know the structure of all the other text you'll be using this regex with.  But if it will always have the one `<env:Header>` element, then you should replace the `.*?` in my regex with `\s*<env:Header[^<>]*>\s*` or whatever is sufficiently specific to avoid runaway matches while still matching everything you want to.

If you want to remove the closing tags too, try this:

```
String strippedOfEnvelopedHeader = msg.replaceAll("(?s)<(\\w+):Envelope[^<>]*>.*?<\\1:Body>\\s*(.*?)\\s*</\\1:Body>\\s*</\\1:Envelope>", "$2");
```

In this regex, the second `.*?` is appropriate if you want to remove the tags regardless of what is inside them.

Answer (score 0):

As a side, why don't you try to get rid of the entire soap message wrapper?

`String strippedOfEnveloped =  msg.replace( "^ (?six) < (.*):Envelope  .*  <\\1:Body> (.*) </\\1:Body> .* $", "\\2" );`

Comment: OP is using Java, not Perl or PHP. In Java single quoted literals always create a character, like C and C++.

Comment: @KennyTM - Ok, I thought so. Thanks. Edit, is the expanded modifier available too? ie: (?x)

Comment: heh. I like this solution, does everything in a single statement, but my issue was really totally forgetting that \1 does escaping in Java. The correct substitution in Java would be $2 rather than \\2. i.e. msg.replaceAll("(?si)<(.*):Envelope.*<\\1:Body>(.*)</\\1:Body>.*", "$2")

Comment: @graney, In Perl, I would use $2 on the replacement side. \\2 on the replacement side is grandfathered in for sed freaks. I sometimes see \\2 used on SO even for PCRE implementations. I thought Java was backwards. Sorry.

Comment: @snl: Oh Java *is* backwards alrighty, just not in the way you are thinking. Anything that confuses you with multiple levels of evaluation the way Java’s regexes do is just as stooppid as trying to program in `csh`.  Try Groovy.  Or Perl.  Or Ruby.  Or anything else.

Comment: @tchrist, even C# is easier to use for regex thanks to verbatim string literals. I have much love for Ruby regex, and really wish Java did something similar.